# Why won't this create a link?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a link with PHP and I am not sure what is wrong with this code.

```
$product_list .= "\n\r " . 'Ticket Download: ' . ": " . <a href=$single_link["url"]>($single_link['name'])</a>  . "\n\r";
```

I know the issue is with the link (meaning between the opening and closing html tags). What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I have tried using the code you have all provided, and I still can't get it to work. I am not sure why.

Comment: what about using quotes on your link?

Comment: Where you getting the ["url"] from?

Comment: The syntax highlighting didn't clue you in?

Comment: It is defined in a different spot of the code it is from a database.

Comment: @BookOfZeus I'm sorry I'm new to PHP and didn't realize. You don't need to be rude and sarcastic.

Comment: @Tom, I wasn't, I said it in a friendly matter. I recommend to use a GUI that allow syntax highlighting, this way you can see right away what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$product_list .= PHP_EOL . 'Ticket Download: <a href="' . $single_link['url'] . '">' . $single_link['name'] . '</a>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should include the anchor tags in the string

```
$product_list .= "\n\r " . 'Ticket Download: ' . ": <a href={$single_link['url']}>({$single_link['name']})</a> \n\r";
```

Comment: You probably want to also output double-quotes around the `href` attribute in the anchor.  Although I guess it might be optional in HTML5 or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You are not opening and closing quotes in the right places.  You can use this:

```
$product_list .= "\n\r Ticket Download: : <a href=\"" . $single_link["url"] . '">('. $single_link['name'] . ")</a>\n\r";
```

There are a bunch of other ways to do it too.  No doubt someone else will have a more elegant answer.  But that's a quick first-pass cleanup of your code to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Adding quotes around the data in the href will also help.

```
$product_list .= "\n\r " . 'Ticket Download: ' . ": " . <a href='{$single_link["url"]}'>($single_link['name'])</a>  . "\n\r";
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a much easier to read syntax for this which uses [`curly braces`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) instead of string concatenation:

```
$product_list .= "\n\r Ticket Download: <a href={$single_link['url']}>({$single_link['name']})</a>\n\r";
```